# Redis is not preserving precision in sorted set

Tags: redis

I am trying to create a scoreboard using redis with precision. But it is rounding off the precision.

e.g

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd leaderboard 30.1441050792000 "item"
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zrevrange leaderboard 0 -1 withscores
1) "item"
2) "30.144105079199999"
```

Is there any way to preserve the precision in redis to store accurate result.

Thanks

Comment: Are your scores always going to be *accurate* to the same number of places after the decimal?

Comment: yes, 13 places after decimal

Answer (score 6):

According to the docs

> Redis sorted sets use a double 64-bit floating point number to
>   represent the score. In all the architectures we support, this is
>   represented as an IEEE 754 floating point number

As such, if you need that much precision you can store integers in the range 0 - 2^53.  Then you can divide by whatever your multiplier is when you read the data.

Example:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd leaderboard 301441050792000 item
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zrevrange leaderboard 0 -1 WITHSCORES
1) "item"
2) "301441050792000"
```

Then you just divide by 1e13.

**NOTE**
The max value this will work with is 900.7199254740992.  After that you go over 53 bits and end up with lost precision.

Comment: Thanks sberry, but i need the scoreboard to be sorted with precision. if redis rounds out the score then, scoreboard may give unexpected result. But will think on your solution to use long number instead of double. Thanks

Comment: It would still be sorted with precision.  As long as your values are less than 900.7199 you should be fine.  If you multiply all the values by 10e13 then they will retain their correct sorting.